# How can I allow my CountDownTimer to reset after the countdown is finished?

Tags: android, eclipse

Hey all, I'm trying to get my CountDownTimer to autoreset back to it's original time after the time reaches zero. Like an infinite loop. Here is the code I have so far (there are 3 timers in total):

```
package com.android.countdown;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class countdown extends Activity {


    public String formatTime(long millis) {
          String output = "00:00";
          long seconds = millis / 1000;
          long minutes = seconds / 60;

          seconds = seconds % 60;
          minutes = minutes % 60;

          String secondsD = String.valueOf(seconds);
          String minutesD = String.valueOf(minutes);

          if (seconds < 10)
            secondsD = "0" + seconds;
          if (minutes < 10)
            minutesD = "0" + minutes;

          output = minutesD + " : " + secondsD;
          return output;
        }

   @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.main);

//Declare Start/Stop button
Button btnstart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnstart);
Button btnstop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnstop);

//Declare Text fields to show time left
final TextView mCounter1TextField=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.counter1);
final TextView mCounter2TextField = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.counter2);
final TextView mCounter3TextField=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.counter3);



//Counter 1
final CountDownTimer Counter1 = new CountDownTimer(120000 , 1000) {
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    mCounter1TextField.setText("Seconds left: " + formatTime(millisUntilFinished));
}

public void onFinish() {
    mCounter1TextField.setText("Finished!");
}
};

//Counter 2
final CountDownTimer Counter2 = new CountDownTimer(80000 , 1000) {
 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
     mCounter2TextField.setText("Seconds left: " + formatTime(millisUntilFinished));
 }

 public void onFinish() {
     mCounter2TextField.setText("Finished!");
 }
 };

//Counter 3
final CountDownTimer Counter3 = new CountDownTimer(10000 , 1000) {
  public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
      mCounter3TextField.setText("Seconds left: " + formatTime(millisUntilFinished));
  }

  public void onFinish() {
      mCounter3TextField.setText("Finished!");
  }
  };


//Start Button
btnstart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
 public void onClick(View v) {
  Counter1.start();
  Counter2.start();
  Counter3.start();
   }
});

//Stop Button
btnstop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
 public void onClick(View v) {
  Counter1.cancel();
  Counter2.cancel();
  Counter3.cancel();
    }
});
}
}
```

I can't figure what to put inside onFinish()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the `CounterX.start()` in the respective `onFinish()`

```
//Counter 1 
final CountDownTimer Counter1 = new CountDownTimer(120000 , 1000) { 
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        mCounter1TextField.setText("Seconds left: " + formatTime(millisUntilFinished)); 
}

public void onFinish() {
    mCounter1TextField.setText("Finished!");
    Counter1.start(); 
}
};
```

Comment: //EDIT\\ I got it working. It turns out the 'final' was screwing it all up. I needed to declare 'CountDownTimer counter;' at the top to get rid of 'final' after that it worked.

Comment: ^ that is why the Counter1.start() was not working for me earlier. Thanks for your input though, I wouldn't have found the solution without it

Comment: Glad it helps :) I have overlooked the final as well, final variable can only be assigned once, so it's not needed at all here.